# Error 102 nginx SSL

Tags: ssl, https, nginx

I can't get SSL work on my domain. I just get 102 connection refused.

Here is the config:

```
  server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.foreningsdriv.se.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
     #if the URL with .php tacked on is a valid PHP file, rewrite the URL to .php
if (-f $document_root$uri.php) {
rewrite ^(.*)$ /$uri.php;
}

        root /var/www/foreningsdriv.se;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name www.foreningsdriv.se;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }

      }
```

Can anyone see anything wrong?

I have tried reissue the certficate but it doesn't help.

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: 2013/08/07 12:35:51 [emerg] 4923#0: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/nginx/ssl/server.key") failed (SSL: error:0906406D:PEM routines:PEM_def_callback:problems getting password error:0906A068:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad password read error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib)

Comment: I'm wondering why when some error is happened nobody ever looking at error logs? That must be the basic reflex of any system administrator.

Ok. The error message is pretty clear: your private key is protected by password, so nginx cannot read it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should remove passphrase from your private key.

```
openssl rsa -in original.key -out unencripted.key
```